# Insert records in table B and later match with source table A

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, insert-update

I have tables A and B with identity PKs `ida` and `idb`:

ex A:

```
ida    col1     col2   idb
---------------------------
1      xxxx     foo    NULL
2      yyyy     bar    NULL
```

ex B:

```
idb    col3     col4  
----------------------
110    uuuu     rrr  
111    vvvv     ttt
```

For each row in A I must insert a row in B. Then  i need to update A with the ID's of the rows I inserted in B **while keeping a match between them. There is no other relation between A and B, and no data from A goes into B.**

After the insert, B might look like this:

```
idb    col3     col4  
----------------------
110    uuuu     rrr  
111    vvvv     ttt   
112    aaaa     www    
113    bbbb     mmm
```

After the update of A, A will look like this for example:

```
ida    col1     col2   idb
---------------------------
1      xxxx     foo    112
2      yyyy     bar    113
```

Now the question is, how do I determine which record from B corresponds to which from A since I have no relations between them? I could insert and update one by one in a loop but for a lot of records this could be problematic.

Is there a way to do this in fewer steps?

Comment: where do the new `col3` and `col4` values come from?  And shouldn't the column `ida` in table `B` be called `idb` instead?

Comment: If it is a 1 to 1 mapping, why not just store the ID of table A in table B rather than the other way around?

Comment: isn't this the scenario for which `Foriegn Keys` are there? So you can make a relation between two tables.

Comment: @Andomar: ups... I fixed the names. As for where the data comes is some constant values that apply to what A represents but the constant values are not unique to each row in A (e.g. it can be 1, 2, 3, 4, 2 again, 1 again etc)

Comment: "but for a lot of records this could be problematic" -- have you measured this? I think you may be surprised.

Comment: @Macros: It's not one to one. A is a temporary table which I then use for other things. It's too complex to explain here. The example above is just part of it that I simplified as much as I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your requirement this is what you can try  to achieve the result

```
  Declare @countA int
  Declare @value int
  set @value =0
  Select @countA=count(*) from TableA

  while @value<@countA
  BEGIN
  Insert into TableB (idb,col3,Col4)
  select max(idb)+1,'aaa','BBBB' from TableB  --I don't know from where you get the values for col3    and col4
  Update TableA
  set idb=(Select max(idb) from TableB) where idb is null and @value+1=ida
  set @value=@value+1
  END
```

Comment: Although not in the same way, I went for a similar approach.

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is if you can construct a [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement that does the insert into table B - because if you can, you can construct an `OUTPUT` clause that references *both* the newly inserted rows in Table B, and the corresponding rows from Table A. You can't do this with an `INSERT` statement unfortunately.

All of the below scripts should be run in one go, just splitting them up to show what's happening:

Data setup:

```
declare @TabA table (ida int IDENTITY(1,1),col1 char(4),col2 char(3),idb int)
insert into @TabA(col1,col2,idb) values 
('xxxx','foo',NULL),
('yyyy','bar',NULL)

declare @TabB table (idb int IDENTITY(110,1),col3 char(4),col4 char(3))
insert into @TabB(col3,col4) values
('uuuu','rrr'),
('vvvv','ttt')
```

`MERGE` being forced to just do an insert. Here, the `CASE` expressions are however you derive the new values from `col3` and `col4` based on the values from table A. Here, I'm using ID, but it's whatever you need to do:

```
declare @Res table (ida int,idb int)

;merge into @TabB tb
using (select ida,col1,col2 from @TabA where idb is null) src
on 1 = 0
when not matched then insert (col3,col4) values (case src.ida when 1 then 'aaaa' else 'bbbb' end,case src.ida when 1 then 'www' else 'mmm' end)
output src.ida,inserted.idb into @Res;
```

Now, `@Res` contains the matching IDs from the two tables, so it's simple to construct an update that copies the new IDs back into table A:

```
update a set idb = r.idb
from @TabA a
inner join @Res r on a.ida = r.ida
```

And the results:

```
select * from @TabA
select * from @TabB

ida         col1 col2 idb
----------- ---- ---- -----------
1           xxxx foo  112
2           yyyy bar  113

(2 row(s) affected)

idb         col3 col4
----------- ---- ----
110         uuuu rrr
111         vvvv ttt
112         aaaa www
113         bbbb mmm
```